# Vb.net two Times togeather HH:MM from to text boxes

Tags: vb.net

So I have 2 labels that the times change I need to add them together they do not stay the same but I cant find a ways to get them to add right. Here is what I have.

```
    Dim Time1, Time2 As String
    Dim TotalTime As Integer

    'The Time that is in Lable is in Hours and Mins.
    'Example 0:13 is 13 Mins
    'Example 1:45 is 1 Hour and 45 mins 
    Time1 = Convert.ToInt32(lblTime1)
    Time2 = Convert.ToInt32(lblTime2)

    TotalTime = Time1 + Time2
End Sub
```

Comment: if the textboxes contain Times then do not convert to string or integer, use a DateTime variable and simply add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx)s out of your labels’ `Text`s:

```
Dim time1 = TimeSpan.ParseExact(lblTime1.Text, "h\:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
Dim time2 = TimeSpan.ParseExact(lblTime2.Text, "h\:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)

Dim totalTime = time1 + time2
```

Comment: @Plutonix: It’s intentional. In C#, it’d be `"h\\:mm"`.

Comment: @minitech how would I add two times From Excel cells in vb.net here is my code oXL.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value + oXL.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value i just need to add thos two vaules in vb.net

Comment: @user3758379: Is `oXL.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value` a string? If so, just pass that to `TimeSpan.ParseExact` instead.

Comment: I did it gives an over Load

Comment: @user3758379: What do you mean? It’s ambiguous?